# in org-mode, how to insert current date for HTML export only?

Tags: html, emacs, elisp, org-mode

I am using an org-mode file to generate both HTML and LaTeX/PDF. I have an HTML code block in my org-mode file. I'd like the date to appear in my HTML code block so that it maintains proper formatting and does not appear in LaTeX export.

I'm not sure I can do this using Javascript, because I don't want the date to dynamically update such that the user will always see the current date; rather, I'd like to include the date at the time I *generate* HTML (i.e. at the time of HTML export).

So that the exported HTML file would say "Last updated February 6, 2014" or whatever.

How do I do this using org-mode?

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros.

In that document (to read the HTML, better clone the repository first, so that CSS/JS is adequate), you'll see the use of the Org built-in time macro in the case you're interested in:

```
This document was last exported on: {{{time(%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M)}}}.
```

As said by others, if needed, you can then have that particular sentence outputted only in HTML exports.

Comment: See http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros/blob/master/README.html for a nice-to-read version of the project.

Answer (score 2):

By [this documentation](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Quoting-HTML-tags) you can either write:

```
 #+HTML: Literal HTML code for export
```

or:

```
 #+BEGIN_HTML
 All lines between these markers are exported literally
 #+END_HTML
```

It is said to be rendered *only* in HTML export. You can also add a save hook that updates the date to the current date every time you save the document, as you can see [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TimeStamp).

Comment: I updated the response to point you where you can add a timestamp with a save hook.

Comment: How do I insert a save hook in the html code block if those lines are exported literally?

Comment: Peter, in the documentation they tell you how to stablish a "prefix" (such as for example "Last modified:" so that the timestamp save hook (stablished in your `.emacs` file) will find that string and *append* the timestamp every time you save the file.